# How to avoid flickering when animating GUI components in Lazarus

Tags: user-interface, animation, lazarus, flicker, tmemo

I'm moving a `TMemo` object left and right in my GUI application. The problem is, is that the letters in my `TMemo` are flickering as soon as the movement starts.

I've looked this up, and, apparently, setting the `DoubleBuffering` property of my main form should've helped me, but it didn't. So I tried setting that property to true on all objects that were moving, but flickering was still present.

Are there any ways to achieve flicker-free animations of GUI components in Lazarus? I'm a novice in Lazarus, so I'm kind of blindly googling for solutions right now. I would really appreciate some help.

To provide further context, here's how I animate my `TMemo`: I've got a `TTimer` with an interval value of 10, and its `OnTimer` event moves my `TMemo` left and right contiguously. To make the movement slightly smoother, I added a simple cosine interpolation function.

In the end here's the code:

```
procedure TServerSideForm.ControlPanelHideTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (hideAnimVal < 1) then
  begin
    hideAnimVal := hideAnimVal + 0.025;
  end
  else
  begin
    MemoHideTimer.Enabled:=false;
  end;


  // hideStart - starting position of my TMemo, hideEnd - end position of my TMemo
  hideCurr := Round(CosineInterpolation(hideStart, hideEnd, hideAnimVal));

  Memo.Left:=hideCurr;
end;
```

Cosine interpolation:

```
function CosineInterpolation(Val1, Val2, Angle: Double): Double;
var
  Percent: Double;
begin
  Percent := (1-Cos(Angle*PI))/2;
  Result := (Val1 * (1 - Percent) + Val2 * Percent);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to move an image instead:

```
var
  Memo1dc: hdc;
  Cnv: TCanvas;
  Rct: TRect;

implementation

procedure TForm1.MemoHideTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Memo1.Visible then
  begin
    Memo1dc := GetDC(Memo1.Handle);
    Cnv.Handle := Memo1dc;
    Rct.Height := Memo1.Height;
    Rct.Width := Memo1.Width;
    Image1.Left := Memo1.Left;
    Image1.Top := Memo1.Top;
    Image1.Width := Memo1.Width;
    Image1.Height := Memo1.Height;
    Image1.Canvas.CopyRect(Rct, Cnv, Rct);
    Memo1.Visible := False;
    Image1.Visible := True;
  end;
  if (hideAnimVal < 1) then
  begin
    hideAnimVal := hideAnimVal + 0.025;
  end
  else
  begin
    MemoHideTimer.Enabled := False;
  end;

  // hideStart - starting position of my TMemo, hideEnd - end position of my TMemo
  hideCurr := Round(CosineInterpolation(hideStart, hideEnd, hideAnimVal));
  Image1.Left := hideCurr;
  if MemoHideTimer.Enabled = False then
  begin
    Memo1.Left := Image1.Left;
    Memo1.Visible := True;
    Image1.Visible := False;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Cnv := TCanvas.Create;
end;
```